# couldn't load plugin - google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash, centos6

My operating system is Centos 6.7, and browser that I use is Google chrome. While I go to most of the video sites, it gives me "couldn't load plugin" error (except youtube). I started wondering why is the error getting popped up, while I had already installed Adobe flash player and the version is   21.0.0.216. So, I decided to do some research on it to solve the issue. What I have understood is that there are two types of flash players, PPAPI and NPAPI, and for my system configuration, it needs NPAPI to be enabled, as given in this link (http://www.tweakjc.com/how-to-fix-chrome-couldnt-load-plug-in-error/#imageclose-113). But, unfortunate for me I don't have an option of NPAPI in my browser plugin list. [screenshot of my AFP in the plugins list, where only PPAPI is available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQAxN.png)

Is there a way to get NPAPI type of AFP, or is my perception is right or is there any other workaround possible to play my vids? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That link is to obsolete information; NPAPI support was completely removed from Chrome last year.

Comment: To correct this bug i deleted all the user data associated with chrome, in Users/Pro/Library/Application%20Support/Google/Chrome (i do not know the equivalent for your OS) and it worked again. Before that I tried every reinstall possible without success.